# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended (When trying to generate a table query, then ordering it by date)

Tags: sql, oracle

So I'm reuploading this question (as I have a new format now)

**The new code:**

SELECT * FROM "Sales Orders"

ORDER BY "EMPLOYEE_LASTNAME" DESC;

SELECT "SALES_ORDER_NUMBER","SALES_ORDER_DATE", "EMPLOYEE_LASTNAME",

"DELIVERY_DUE_DATE", "DELIVERY_CHARGE" FROM "Sales Orders"

WHERE "SALES_ORDER_DATE" BETWEEN '05/09/2016' AND '12-12-2016';

**The code works separately, but not together (and I can't figure out why).**

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFG3a.png)

Comment: Remove the quotes from the table and column name.

Comment: Clearly error message belongs to `Oracle` so removing irrelevant tags

Comment: Using a proper editor with syntax highlighting would help here. Even the StackOverflow code formatting shows the error: the missing quote mark means the code words (SELECT, VALUE) are not coloured correctly in the last three statements, which is a big clue as to what and where the error is.

Answer (score 1):

In your second `Insert` statement for `DELIVERY_DUE_DATE` single quotes is missing

```
INSERT INTO "Sales Orders" ("SALES_ORDER_NUMBER", "SALES_ORDER_DATE", "EMPLOYEE_IDENTIFIER", "DELIVERY_DUE_DATE", "DELIVERY_CHARGE")
VALUES (1000175110, '12-12-2016', '1', '01-12-2017', 8);
                                     --^here
```

Comment: @Lilac.Galaxy - Hey, I have added a single quote before `01-12-2017` which is missing in your code. Nothing to do with luck ;)